# Responsive hover content div into different position

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, concrete5

here is my responsive parallax site i’m working on with Concrete5 Bootstrap theme
–> http://testi4.aada.fi/ and there is BUSINESS GROUPS content area in frontpage.
that’s what i’m working on right now.

Now hower image with content opens over div with content (list)..

Now customer wants that hover div opens below image div with list as a content..

http://testi4.aada.fi/files/8214/1744/4748/sample.png

How do i do this??

// Mika

Answer (score 0):

Add a hover class to your `li.dropdown`

```
.navbar-nav li.dropdown {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for help..did u check my sample img? scroll down my site so u can see what i'm after..